# what does ntp4 stand for in Chrome source code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

"chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/ntp4/"

I'm trying to figure out the process that how chrome create the new tab page. I wonder what the 'ntp4' stands for. Hope to get some help.

Comment: It seems like the abbr for NewTabPage 4th edition?

Comment: Probably :D, I'm just giving you my first google search result though :p

Comment: I'm pretty sure it _is_ New Tab Page v4, lol.

Answer (score 0):

It stands for New Tab Page v4.

Comment: Did you ever read the source codes? I need some help with it.